# Make ChartLabels appear only for the outer layer of data

Tags: charts

I am using the following code to produce the graph below. I would like to modify its `ChartLabels` so they appear only for the outermost layer.

```
data = {{"Benefit_type", "IP", "OP", "OPT", "DNT", 
    "MTR"}, {"older_earned_net_premium", 134., 223., 345., 234., 
    234.}, {"previous_earned_net_premium", 54., 175., 235., 234., 
    123.}};

PieChart[
        #[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]/(Plus @@@ (#[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]))*100,
        LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Row[{NumberForm[#, {3, 1}], "%"}], 
       "RadialCenter"] &),
        ChartLabels -> Placed[#[[1, 2 ;;]], "RadialCallout"],
        LabelStyle -> FontSize -> 12,
        PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
        ImageSize -> Large
    ] &@data
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the reproducable code?

Comment: I have added the reproducible code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the last dataset with `Labeled` and remove `ChartLabels`:

```
Module[{d = 100 Normalize[#, Total] & /@ #[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]], labels = #[[1, 2 ;;]]}, 
   d[[-1]] = Thread[Labeled[d[[-1]], labels, "RadialCallout"]]; 
   PieChart[d, 
     LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Row[{NumberForm[#, {3, 1}], "%"}], "RadialCenter"] &), 
     LabelStyle -> FontSize -> 12, ImageSize -> Large]] &@data
```

[image]

Comment: Although i needed it to work for any number of data layers not just two but using `Slot` function i was able to generalize your solution. Thank you!